# Comparing Files to a list of MD5 Hashes and getting a List as Result (where i can delete, copy, cut etc. the results)

Tags: comparison, hashing, list

I am searching for a solution for the following situation. I have a list of Hashes in a Text File and i want to find every File in a certain folder and subfolders that matches the Hashes from the Text File.

The found Files will be listed as a Result and i would love to be abel to delete (or maybe move or copy) those found files...

Is there any easy (software tool) way to do this ? Or does someone have a workaround ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In order to "match" a MD5 hash to a file, you would have to provide the same input that generated the MD5 hash originally, since you cannot reverse the MD5 hash into a filename.  Do you know how the MD5 was generated?  Assuming you know that information what have you attempted?  Generating an MD5 hash is relatively simply with PowerShell.  However, in order to "prettify"  the output, the more complex the script can become.

Comment: i dont know if i understand you correctly...i have no interest in the filenames whatsoever so basically i want a tool that hashes all MY files and compares those hashes to the ones in my txt file and if they match list it to me otherwise ignore my file. I am well aware this will take some time.

Comment: You would have to write a tool that does what you describe.  I mention filenames because MD5 only takes text input.  I will repeat for your benefit you would have to provide it the same input to generate the same MD5 hashes.  It does not sound like you know how the MD5 hashes in your input file were generated.

Comment: You can use a BASH script. Create the MD5 hashes of all files in your folders and then compare them to your list. Then take action on matches.

Comment: @zx485 yeah i kinda hoped theres a software for that already :D thanks thou